# How to get an image draggable AND resizable and the div only resizable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to hava a resizable `div`, in which every image is resizable and draggable.
I used the `jquery-ui` to handle that, but it is not working. I cannot resize the div and I can only drag or resize it.

This is my code:

```
  <div draggable="true" class="div" id="content" contenteditable="true" >
    <img src = "test.jpg" id = "img" class="img"> 
  </div><br>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#content').resizable();
    $('#img').resizable(
        animate: true
        ghost: true
    ).parent().draggable({
        scroll: true
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code must be like:

```
  <div  class="div" id="content" contenteditable="true" >
    <img  src="http://store.valvesoftware.com/images/sizing_chart_shirt.png" id = "img" class="img"/> 
  </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#content').draggable();

        $('#img').resizable({
             animate: true,
             ghost: true
          });
    </script>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/C204qZ)